# Close FancyBox with Redirect::back() Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, fancybox-2

I am creating a project using Laravel

In my view I'm using Fancybox-2 to display a form. When the form is submitted I want the Fancybox to close and then have the user redirected to another page.

In my controller, at the end of the method that processes the form, I have

```
// some code

return Redirect::route('Page')
```

When I submit my form from the view, everything works. The database is filled and I'm redirected to 'Page'. However I'm redirect in the Fancybox. How do I close the fancy box and then redirect to 'Page' within my controller? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to handle the redirect with javascript. I suggest you return a JSON object from the controller and then read that out in your callback function:

```
if(Request::ajax()){
    return Response::json(array('redirect' => route('Page')));
}
return Redirect::route('Page')
```

Javascript:

```
function(response){
   if(response.redirect){
       window.location = response.redirect;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm but now fancybox does not open. The content of the Fancybox loads in it own page.

Comment: I hope you haven't just inserted the javascript code in your page. It's supposed to be an example how to handle the callback from your controller. If you need further assistance please update your question with the javascript code you have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laravel but in order to close fancybox (I assume it's an `iframe` type) you need to call the `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()`  method from the opened page.

Then, in your fancybox custom initialization script (the one you missed to show in your question), add the `afterClose` callback to redirect the page to wherever you want like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // other API options
    afterClose : function() {
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/page.html";
    }
});
```